# Ajax call return empty API response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am posting email on a API URL using a HTML form and PHP code with a Ajax call. but response is empty. I want to print the response on the same page under form. I am posting my all code here and want to know what wrong i am doing. Currently i am working on my localhost XAMP server, Does that also matter?

My HTML

```
<form method="post">
          <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-10 col-xs-12 mid-align">
            <div class="input-group margin-top-35 mid-align">
              <input type="email" name="email" class="mob-row form-control text-box" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email address">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default join" type="submit">JOIN US</button>
              </span>
            </div><!-- /input-group -->
          </div>
        </form>
```

My PHP code

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$email = trim($_POST['email']);

    $url = 'https://slack.com/api/users.admin.invite?token=$token&email='.$email.'';

    $response = file_get_contents($url);
    echo $response;
```

My Ajax call

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var e = $(".error");
    $(".join").click(function() {
        var a = $("#email").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "post-data.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                email: a
            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(response);
                },
            success: function(a) {
            console.log(response);
                a.ServiceOperationResult.success ? e.hide() : e.html(a.ServiceOperationResult.messageText).show()
            },

        })
    })
})
```

Comment: You're success method is accepting in the variable `a`.  Where is `response` supposed to be coming from.... ?

Comment: Agreed with @Taplar . do `console.log(a);` and check

Comment: @Taplar changed to `a` but still empty

Comment: Try commenting out `dataType: "json",` and see if your console log prints anything.

Comment: @Taplar no luck

Comment: If you took out the dataType, and you are console.log(a) in your success method, it runs, and you get blank; then your php is not returning anything

Comment: @Taplar Do you have any suggestion for PHP code?

Comment: Verify that it's hitting the right file.  Verify that the $response is getting the value you expect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158724/discussion-between-rohit-chaudhary-and-taplar).

Answer (score 0):

The form is getting submitted and refreshing the page so the ajax call is not executing. I suggest you to remove the  tag and try again. This  time the ajax will start working and you can check it using console.log();

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove post from your form tag
2. Keep the keys in your ajax data element in single quotes
3. rectify your console.log statements
4. Make sure $token is field is defined in your php file

Answer (score 0):

Two totally different questions may have the same answer, none of the two can be the duplicate of the other.

As here, obviously the principle of returning a link to a first question leading to the same answer seems forbidden, I put here the same copy of the code that I use myself to send and receive JSON data between a browser and a server PHP.

I've been using it for a lot of years, and this code has been improved over time, with noticeable problems with cache management, which can be a problem with some browsers (see even versions of jQuery, but I do not will not launch into this kind of questioning), For those who want to continue to doubt the validity of this question, I suggest they do a search on google with the following lerms: "jquery ajax problems json cache" to realize that everything is not necessarily so simple on this issue.

In the end, I consider this piece of code perfectly reliable, and I will continue to use it in the same state.

Nothing prevents you from removing the line of code putting the cache to false; for my part I would not quibble about this detail.

So, here is this code : "The way I use jQuery-ajax  with php"

jQuery Part :  (JSON is simpler than our mind can imagine ?)

```
    var 
        Call_Args = {
            what:  $('#id_what').val(),
            why:  $('#id_why').val(),
            who:  $('#id_who').val() 
        },
        answer_1 = '',
//      ...
        answer_n = '';

        $.ajax({
            url: 'assets/php/the_Called_PHP_Function.php',  // path is from html file
            type: 'POST',
            data: Call_Args,
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function (request, error) {
                alert("Error : responseText: " + request.responseText); // don't mind, it's never happened
            },
            success: function (data) {
                answer_1 = data['rep_1'];
                answer_n = data['rep_n'];

                // your javascript stuff here... remember, ajax is asynchrone...
            } 

        });
```

php part ( 'assets/php/the_Called_PHP_Function.php' )

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");   // !important, characters have many awards for stupid traps

    $ref_what   = (isSet($_POST['what']))       ? $_POST['what']        : '';
    $ref_why        = (isSet($_POST['why']))        ? $_POST['why']     : '';
    $ref_who        = (isSet($_POST['who']))        ? $_POST['who']     : '';

// your php code stuff here...

    $T_Repons['rep_1']          = 'bla bla bla';
// ...
    $T_Repons['rep_n']          = 'turlututu...';


header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($T_Repons);
exit(0);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your button type submit to button, because your form will submit using submit button.

type="submit"

to

type="button"

Answer (score -1):

i hope u jokn bro, frst: u not define $token, scnd: u use ' but u need use " to parse vars into quots like "https://slack.com/api/users.admin.invite?token=$token&email=".$email." or like  'https://slack.com/api/users.admin.invite?token='.$token.'&email='.$email.', thrd: u need to use variable a as response if u write succes:function(a), and more other things in ur code, sry for my ez eng, im write it on phone so fast